# ParseUser unable to be logged in after migrating to MongoLab

Tags: android, heroku, parse-platform, mlab

So I'm rebuilding an Android app after grieving the shutdown of Parse, and am trying to lean on Heroku and MongoLab to host my data as outlined in [this tutorial.](https://learnappmaking.com/how-to-migrate-parse-app-parse-server-heroku-mongolab/)

I've been able to save and read custom objects as well as save new ParseUser objects. I just can't successfully log users in (which I was able to do previously with just Parse).

Here is a snippet of my code, after I've enabled local datastore and initialized Parse:

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(),
            new LogInCallback() {
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                Dashboard.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Successfully Logged in",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "No such user exists, please signup",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Running this doesn't throw any errors, but the user is not logged in and the "No such user exists, please signup" toast is shown.

Does MongoLab somehow encrypt the passwords in a way that ParseUser's login methods can't read? If you have any ideas on what the issue could be, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Claire, you can try writing into our support (support@mongolab.com) and we can take a look to see if we can find anything in the database logs that might provide a clue to what's going on. Passwords for MongoDB/MongoLab are strings.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue. My problem ended up being the fact that I built my Android app pointing to localhost instead of to the actual IP address where my instance of Parse Server was running.

My initial (faulty) code:

```
Parse.initialize(
        new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .applicationId(PARSE_APPLICATION_ID)
                .clientKey(PARSE_CLIENT_KEY)
                .server("http://localhost:1337/parse/") // HERE
                .build());
```

Which works with the correct IP address:

```
Parse.initialize(
        new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .applicationId(PARSE_APPLICATION_ID)
                .clientKey(PARSE_CLIENT_KEY)
                .server("http://192.168.1.9:1337/parse/") // HERE
                .build());
```